# Getting Build Error while runnning CLI - npm run build in react-ts project where i used antdesign layout

Tags: typescript, deployment, build, ant-design-pro, npm-build

## [This is a screenshot after runnibg npm run build in a terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qI7Xo.png)

When I am running cli command npm run build  for making a build for deploying I am getting this error as shown in terminal, my project i made using ant-design layout based on Typescript-react, I tried to mention data types in all but still getting the same error there, please let me know what action should i take to  make a build folder for deploying my project

Comment: Try adding `exclude: ["node_modules"] in tsconfig.json` file